# Python Idle: Why does the dash key show a comma instead?

Tags: python, format, python-idle

Whenever I type in "-" python idle converts it to ","

I have redownloaded python to the most recent update
I don't think its my computers problem bc I can type - just fine
Typing - works fine in python cmd, just not in idle

Normally I could live with the format but I have an assignment where the "-" key needs to be shown
For example:

If I wanted "2-3" idle converts it to "2 ,3"

(Subtraction still works fine, the formatting is just weird)

---

Image of Dash problem:

[image]

I asked my CS professor about it and he said he had never seen it before so I figured asking around and checking if any one else has the same problem

Comment: Does this ONLY happen in Idle? What about Word or Excel?

Comment: That's an odd one. Even if an encoding error were giving you the wrong character, you'd expect it to be consistent between input and output.

Comment: Any chance you can provide screenshots, or a GIF, of this happening? It's a bit unclear whether this is changing on input, or as you type, whether it shows `2,3` but somehow still does `2-3` (font issue?), or what.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you copy what you write from IDLE into a different editor, like Notepad or other word-processors, does the dashes show correctly, or are they still spaces and commas as in the picture?

Comment: That's a weird font for programming. It's much more common to use a monospaced font, and that should be the default in IDLE. If you go into the Options menu, then select Configure IDLE, then pick the Fonts tab, what Font Face is selected as the Shell/Editor Font?

Comment: Actually... now that I look at the menus in your screenshot, they don't match my IDLE. What version of Python are you using? In any case, please dig into the Options menu there and see if you can find the font settings, then respond to my previous comment.

Comment: The symbol being printed as a dash is not a comma, as comma is slanted and narrowly spaced and the symbol is vertical and sidely spaced.  If you enter 2-3 in the interactive shell and return, what response do you see?  Note that symbol printing is handled by Tk, not IDLE.  Perhaps you are using a foreign language font that prints - as that vertical bar.  Or you have turned on a foreign language setting for your keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using a font that didn't support the dash symbol, kinda stupid of me to not realize looking back on it

Thank you @TerryJanReedy for making me realize this

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I'll think about adding this as a possibility somewhere in the IDLE doc.